# Twilio Ability to use same number for two simultaneous outgoing calls?

Tags: api, grails, twilio

I have a helpdesk app I am developing for a client and they have a few people they have on as call people. Does each one need a different twilio number to be able to call out at the same time to different people? I have tried this already with my current setup but it only conferences the two people with the caller. I am using the twilio soft phone feature to allow agents to call out to different numbers. Do they each need to have a separate twilio number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not at all. If you have already verified an outgoing number, you can use that or any Twilio number that you have on your account as the caller id. You certainly don't need a number per agent for outgoing calls.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Found [this link](https://twilio.radicalskills.com/projects/call-center-planning/2.html), _Inbound calling_ section could be helpful.